# Why my Android onPrepareOptionsMenu called when I click the MenuIten

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

I use the onPrepareOptionsMenu method to load my menu for the Toolbar, because I need the change the menu item when I show the diferent framgnet.

And now I have a problem that when I click the more icon to show the overflow menu, the menu items on the toolbar change two double, as the picture, there are two search menu item

[image]

I have debug for this, and I found that when I click the more menu item, the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` method will call again.

here is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_selection, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mSearchView.setMenuItem(item);
    return true;
}
```

my menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_menu_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_hint_search"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share_selection"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:title="@string/menu_hint_share"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_feedback_selection"
    android:orderInCategory="102"
    android:title="@string/menu_hint_feedback"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

What can I do for this? some help please! thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still no the reason, but I found a way which I think it's stupid is I whi
`menu.clear();` before I inflate the layout menu. Should any of your guys have some better implement way.